# call a function with php dropdown

Tags: php, function, dropdown

I have this code from index.php. my database connection is set in index.php & sql query also is ok. After call to the function then not working.

```
<?php
  $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'root', '');
?>
<?php
  include('function.php');
?>
<form class="form-horizontal" name="myform" action="index.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Institute</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <select class="form-control" name="institute"  id="institute">
            <option class="col-lg-6" value="" selected="selected" >- Select Institute -</option>
            <?php 
              echo fill_institute_list($connect);   
            ?>
            </select>


        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

then call to function.php

```
function fill_institute_list($connect)
{
    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM cadre_institute
    ORDER BY institute ASC
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    $output = '';
    foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["institute"].'</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

---

then in browser not display after dropdown field..

Comment: _then not working_ Not helpful description of a problem! Did you check for errors in the log file?

Comment: PHP versions prior to 8.0 did not show PDO errors by default. You need to [tell it otherwise](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) right after you connect to your database.

Answer (score 0):

try change these

```
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["institute"].'</option>';
```

to

```
        $output .= '<option value="'.$row[id].'">'.$row[institute].'</option>';
```